# Set indexed attribute of a lucene field?

Tags: java, lucene

I have a big lucene index produced by 3rd party.

I want to search over a field which is not indexed. Is it possible to re-create the index with that field being now indexed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself, just using an index reader and a writer.
I dunno if it's the proper way. The field was a string field (stored), so for this case, it just worked.

```java
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(...);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(...);

for(int i = 0; i < reader.maxDoc(); i++) {
    if(reader.isDeleted(i)) continue;
    Document d = reader.document(i);
    Document d2 = new Document();
    for(Field f : (List<Field>)d.getFields()) {
        Field f2 = f;
        if(f.name().equals(FIELD_NAME))
            f2 = new Field(FIELD_NAME, f.stringValue(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
        d2.add(f2);
    }
    writer.addDocument(d2);
}

writer.optimize();
writer.close();
```

Comment: You should note that this will only get the stored fields of the document.  Fields that are indexed but unstored will be lost using this approach.  This may be fine for your case, but it's fairly typical for large content-heavy fields to be indexed only.

Comment: for the sake of knowledge, is there a valid approach for such case?

Comment: If you have the control over how the index is built, change the field in question to an be indexed.  If you don't control the index build process, you could do much like what you are doing there, but keep it around as a secondary index just for such searches, and store a pointer to the appropriate record in the primary index (NOT a DocId).  You can't really rebuild un-stored data from the index.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that field is stored right? If not, you are out of luck.

If it is stored, you have several options, I think the easiest would be:

1. dump all docs as csv output ([see here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CSVResponseWriter))
2. change that field's schema to indexed=true
3. then reindex all of them (csv output can be used for update as well)